# C# language, Calculator

Tags: c#, calculator

Hello everyone and thanks for helping me.

I made this calculator in C# and i got one problem.
When i add something like 5+5+5 it gives me correct result but when i want to substract more than two number and also divide or multiply more than two number i don't get correct result.

Do you know what i am doing wrong,

Thank you very much!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace calculator
{
    public partial class Calculator : Form
    {
        public Calculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnOne.Text;
            //txtDisplay.Text = btnOne.Text;
        }

        private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnTwo.Text;
        }

        private void btnThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnThree.Text;
        }

        private void btnFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnFour.Text;
        }

        private void btnFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnFive.Text;
        }

        private void btnSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnSix.Text;
        }

        private void btnSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnSeven.Text;
        }

        private void btnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnEight.Text;
        }

        private void btnNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnNine.Text;
        }

        private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + btnZero.Text;
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + ",";
        }


        double total1 = 0;
        double total2 = 0;

        bool plusButtonClicked = false;
        bool minusButtonClicked = false;
        bool divideButtonClicked = false;
        bool multiplyButtonClicked = false;

        private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            plusButtonClicked = true;
            minusButtonClicked = false;
            divideButtonClicked = false;
            multiplyButtonClicked = false;

            total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }

        private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            plusButtonClicked = false;
            minusButtonClicked = true;
            divideButtonClicked = false;
            multiplyButtonClicked = false;

            total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Clear();
        }



        private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Clear();

            plusButtonClicked = false;
            minusButtonClicked = false;
            divideButtonClicked = true;
            multiplyButtonClicked = false;
        }

        private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Clear();

            plusButtonClicked = false;
            minusButtonClicked = false;
            divideButtonClicked = false;
            multiplyButtonClicked = true;
        }



        private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (plusButtonClicked == true)
            {
                total2 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            }

            else if (minusButtonClicked == true)
            {
                total2 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            }

            else if (divideButtonClicked == true)
            {
                total2 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            }

            else if (multiplyButtonClicked == true)
            {
                total2 = total1 * double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            }


            txtDisplay.Text = total2.ToString();
            total1 = 0;
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: place a break point and step through the code line by line and see if the result is expected at each point, once you see the point where its going wrong you will know how to fix it

Comment: Hint: there is a reason scientific calculators use brackets to split each sum to show what has priority, e.g you have the number 10, you want to divide it by 10 then divide that by 2, 10/10 = 1, 1/2 = 0.5 BUT this is different to 10 divided by (10/2) which gives 10/5 which is 2 not half, BIDMAS is very important to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is has not been thoroughly tested. Why don't you try something like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
    public enum Operator
    {
        None,
        Add,
        Minus,
        Divide,
        Multiply
    }

    public partial class Calculator : Form
    {
        private double total = 0;
        private double currentValue = 0;
        private Operator currentOperator;

        public Calculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnOne.Text);
        }

        private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnTwo.Text);
        }

        private void btnThree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnThree.Text);
        }

        private void btnFour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnFour.Text);
        }

        private void btnFive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnFive.Text);
        }

        private void btnSix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnSix.Text);
        }

        private void btnSeven_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnSeven.Text);
        }

        private void btnEight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnEight.Text);
        }

        private void btnNine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnNine.Text);
        }

        private void btnZero_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInput(btnZero.Text);
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentOperator = Operator.None;
            txtDisplay.Clear();
            total = 0;
        }

        private void btnPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + '.';
        }

        private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyOperator(Operator.Add);
        }

        private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyOperator(Operator.Minus);
        }

        private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyOperator(Operator.Divide);
        }

        private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyOperator(Operator.Multiply);
        }

        private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Evaluate();
            txtDisplay.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
        }

        private void Evaluate()
        {
            switch (currentOperator)
            {
                case Operator.Add:
                    total += currentValue;
                    break;
                case Operator.Minus:
                    total -= currentValue;
                    break;
                case Operator.Divide:
                    total /= currentValue;
                    break;
                case Operator.Multiply:
                    total *= currentValue;
                    break;
                case Operator.None:
                    break;
            }
            currentValue = 0;
            currentOperator = Operator.None;
        }

        private void ApplyOperator(Operator op)
        {
            if (currentOperator != Operator.None)
            {
                Evaluate();
            }
            else
            {
                total = double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            }
            txtDisplay.Clear();
            currentOperator = op;
        }

        private void ShowInput(String n)
        {
            txtDisplay.Text = txtDisplay.Text + n;
            currentValue = double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

I would still recommend that you would end up making some form of operator parser. Take a look [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/37428-converting-and-evaluating-infix-postfix-and-prefix-expressions-in-c/) or look in to the 'Shunting Yard' algorithm yourself.

Comment: not to mention BIDMAS is important in determining what priority each action has

Comment: @RhysW Absolutely. I thought about saying this. In fact, I shall add it. However, he is only applying one operation at a time.

Comment: though whilst i was on about BIDMAS and importance of priority i didnt even notice all of them added the numbers it was given XD nice catch

Comment: i understand this but if i put minus in this line i got this result:
for example: 10 - 5 - 3 
result is -18 becouse total1 is 0 at begining and then he make this: 0-10=-10 becouse 
"total1 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);"  
and then -10-5-3 is -18. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @RhysW this sort of solves this BIDMAS problem by limiting the calculation to one operation at a time

Answer (score 2):

The logic for calculating the product, quotient, and difference in your code is `total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);` which is why the addition works, but nothing else. So change the logic so it either divides, multiplies, or subtracts, instead of adding.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it. What the minus_clicked code is doing is adding all of the operands EXCEPT the last one together, and then the equals_clicked code is doing the arithmetic on the result of minus_clicked, and the value of the textbox (which is the last operand, I assume). So, since the operation you're doing in minus_clicked is addition, what you're getting for x - y - z is really:

```
(X + Y) - Z
```

I would consider refactoring a little bit, but if you wanted to keep the code the way it is, I'd probably just change the minus_clicked code to subtract rather than add.

Also, @rhysw is right. If you wan't this to be fully functional, you're gonna have to add priority logic to it as well.

Answer (score 2):

in your code:

```
 private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            total1 = total1 + double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            txtDisplay.Clear();

            plusButtonClicked = false;
            minusButtonClicked = false;
            divideButtonClicked = false;
            multiplyButtonClicked = true;
        }
```

you aren't applying the correct operator, you have total1 = total1 + ...  Change the operator to *.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the code, and it looks like in each button you're just adding each time. So any time to click a button you're just going to keep adding. Just change the opps to their appropriate button. like so:

```cs
private void btnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    plusButtonClicked = false;
    minusButtonClicked = true;
    divideButtonClicked = false;
    multiplyButtonClicked = false;

    total1 = total1 - double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    txtDisplay.Clear();
}

private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    total1 = total1 / double.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
    txtDisplay.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = false;
    minusButtonClicked = false;
    divideButtonClicked = true;
    multiplyButtonClicked = false;
}
```