# Making a calculation according to the BODMAS in C#

Tags: c#, calculator

Guys I have a calculation that is built by a user in a text box.
In short, he defines the format he wants and the values are passed on later(after some database queries).

eg. 
    (X + Y) * 55

or he may also bulid as

```
(X - 100) * 100
```

Is there any way of computing this with c# ?

NOTE : X and Y are retrieved from a database.

Comment: Have you ever built a string/script parser before?

Comment: @rhughes , No I havent.

Comment: This will basically entail creating a small script parser. Depending on your time, you could either look into a pre-built one like Lua, or create your own. How is your time?

Comment: I got 26 hours for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating a mathematical expression in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216735/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-c-sharp)

Comment: But duplicate doesn't have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at http://NCalc.Codeplex.com

its an easy to use and extensibile calculation engine for C#

Example of how to use is :

```
 Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
  Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
```

Comment: Assert is used to verify(if im not wrong) if the evaluation is true or false. I do not need this, I need a way to actually evaluate the expression.

Comment: sure, so just call string results = e.Evaluate().ToString()

Comment: or if you need a double use double result = Convert.ToDouble(e.Evaluate());

Answer (score 0):

Without doing it for you, you could either look [here](http://ttuxen.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/embedding-lua-in-dotnet/) for information about using Lua in C#.

For another way you could create a system like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451647/c-sharp-language-calculator?rq=1) which creates an actual calculator. You could extend it by adding `(` and `)` buttons to compute those first.