# Evaluating a mathematical expression in c#

Tags: c#, function, expression, calculator, evaluation

Guys I have to evaluate a mathematical expression(which is represented by a string).
Till now I had simple expressions thus the following was working fine

```
var result = new DataTable().Compute(STRING_HERE, null);
```

However now my string expression is becoming a bit more complex and the above method is starting to give errors.

Any idea of how I can handle this situation ?

Please I would like some kind of inbuilt method or function like apporach(preferably).

Comment: Give us successful and error inputs, please.

Comment: Could you give any example of what kind of mathematical expressions you want to be able to evaluate? Is it `1+1` or `sum(0, 10, i, {integral(0,i,x,{x})}) ^ (PI*i)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20210926/50447

Comment: so my simple ones were as (X+Y)*100, and worked. But as soon as I do (X+Y)*1(5*5) It no more works.

Comment: `(X+Y)*1(5*5)` might not even be valid in the first place depending on the exact syntax of the method you're currently using. (Missing `*` sign.)

Answer (score 1):

Not inbuild, but NCalc (http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) is a very nice library for evaluating math expressions.